# Howto: Searching for a string in a file from the Windows command line?

Tags: regex, windows, command-line, grep, command-prompt

Is there a way to search a directory and its subdirectories' files for a string?  The string is rather unique.  I want to return the name of the string and hopefully the line that the string is on in the file.  Is there anything built into Windows for doing this?

Comment: I think that you can do this using powershell 2.0 + ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for the built-in [`findstr` command](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732459%28WS.10%29.aspx).

The `/S`  option performs a recursive search.

Answer (score 2):

There is the `find.exe` command, but it's pretty limited in its capabilities. You could install Cygwin or Unxutils and use a pipeline including its Unix-style `find` and `grep`:

```
find . -type f | xargs grep unique-string
```

Comment: Unix-style `grep` should support `-R` for recursive search through a directory tree. The `find`/`xargs` invocations should be unnecessary.

Comment: That's true, most implementations of `grep` do support `-R`. However, some don't, and even with those that do, it's awkward to limit the *files* searched to `*.c` or whatever, because that will omit directories that don't also match `*.c`.